# Absolute path of data directory in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

When I try to use the `SHOW data_directory;` from the server computer, it shows the output as :

> C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data

And I need to get the data directory path 
from the client machine so I used the same `SHOW data_directory;` command but it's still showing the output as : `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data`,

What I am trying to achieve here is :

`\\pg_server_comp\C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data`

I need guidance here on how this can be achieved. Also, if I am missing something that can be corrected to achieve the output.

OS : - Windows

Comment: That is the absolute path. Pgsql doesn't really care about the server name, so you can't get that from there. If you want an UNC path, you could manually try to construct it from that, if you know the server name, but there's no guarantee that the server will allow access to that. Not to mention possible clustering configurations.

Comment: Why do you think you need that?